# Kibana - can I add a monitor on a scripted field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In Kibana (ElasticSearch v6.8) I'm storing documents containing a `date` field and a `LaunchTime` field, and I have a scripted field `uptime` as their difference (in seconds):

```
(doc['date'].value.millis - doc['LaunchTime'].value.millis) / 1000 / 60
```

I'm trying to create a monitor (under alerting) on the max value of this field of the index, but the field 'Uptime' doesn't show up in the list of fields I can do a max query on. Its type is `number` and in visualisations I can do max/min etc. displays of this field.

Is this a limitation of Kibana alerting - that I can't use a scripted field? Or is there some way I can make it available to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is a limitation of kibana's scripted fields. See [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/watcher-alert-for-an-scripted-field/169518) about the same subject referring to the [scripted field official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/scripted-fields.html). I believe that the watcher are handled by ES itself while the scripted field are handled by kibana (they can be used in discovery and visualisations because kibana is handlind those too)

But have no fear! you already have the script for the calculation and you could just add it into logstash to add the field to you actual documents when you index them, which would enable you to use it for watchers AND would probably optimize the load at runtime, since the val is only calculated one, when you ingest it. Then you could run an update by query with a the script and add the field in you existing documents.

If you don't use logstash, you could look into ES's ingestion pipelines, but it's a rather advanced subject and i'm not sure if it was implemented in 5.x.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm currently submitting these documents to ES through a lambda, it's already doing a little work to enhance the documents so we can add another field there easily enough. Good to know that Logstash supports it too because we'll be using that for getting some other data into Kibana soon :)